# Nested model in json in has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following code:

```
# month.rb                        
class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :days

  def map_markers
    days.as_json(
      :only => :position,
      :include => {
        :day_shops => { 
          :only => :position, 
          :include => {
            :shops => {
              :only => [ :name ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    )
  end
end

# day.rb
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :month
  has_many :day_shops
  has_many :shops, :through => :day_shops
end

# day_shop.rb
class DayShop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :day
  belongs_to :shop
end

# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

What I am trying to achieve is to wrap the `shop` model in the `day_shop` model (which is a `through` table), but when I wrapped it up in the JSON like above, I get:

```
undefined method 'shops' for #<DayShop id: 87, day_id: 26, shop_id: 1, position: 1>
```

My expected JSON would be:

```
- position: 1
  :day_shops:
  - position: 1
    :shops:
    - name: Company A
  - position: 2
    :shops:
    - name: Company B
- position: 2
  :day_shops:
  - position: 1
    :shops:
    - name: Company A
  - position: 2
    :shops:
    - name: Company C
```

How can I change my method? Thanks.

Comment: Try `:shop` instead of `:shops` in your `map_markers` method as the `DayShop belongs to a Shop`.

Comment: @SybariteManoj, my silly mistake. Can you post an answer so that I can mark it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DayShop belongs to a Shop` while you are including `shops` to a `day_shop` in your `map_marker` method. Modify `map_marker` to:

```
def map_markers
  days.as_json(
    :only => :position,
    :include => {
      :day_shops => { 
        :only => :position, 
        :include => {
          :shop => {
            :only => [ :name ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  )
end
```